# Store in 2D Array the contents of file LUA

Tags: random, lua

I have a data.txt that contains rows and columns of numbers and I would like to store its content to a 2D array. So basically i'm looking for how to assign objects from file read to a 2D array. By the way, i'm using LUA and just a newbie to it.

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that the language is called Lua, not LUA. It is not an acronym like PHP, so it should not be written in upper case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
local mt = {}          -- create the matrix

for line in io.lines'datafile.txt' do
  local new_row = {}
  for n in line:gmatch'%S+' do
     table.insert(new_row, tonumber(n))
  end
  if #new_row > 0 then
     table.insert(mt, new_row)
  end
end
```

This code will silently skip all non-numeric words.

Comment: thanks for answering but what if I don't know the number of rows and columns?

Comment: You could use io.lines generic for to nicely iterate through all  lines